# array.find() always shows the same array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm currently learning JS/jQuery and thought I'd code a quiz for practice. While I managed to code the basics of the quiz I am struggling with a crucial part of my code.

In this quiz, I have an Array containing 10 objects. Each object has a question (String), options (Array), an answer (String) and a Boolean which indicates whether or not a question has been answered. Further, I filter this array to include only those elements, that haven't been asked/answered yet. However, this unansweredArr always contains 10 elements, even if I call the function again before asking the new question.

What I aim to do is the following:

1. Generate an array, that holds every question that hasn't been
   answered yet. This is being done with

`var unansweredArr = data.filter(function(question){
    return question.answered === false;
});`

2. Then I generate a random number, which will be used to grab an element out of this array. Said element then is being displayed in my HTML
3. When the player clicks on an option, the given answer will be checked. If correct, the player's score will be increased by 1 and the next question will be asked. Also `answered: false` will be set to `answered: true` on that specific question.

Until step 3, everything works like a charm (for me ;)) However, step 4 and further are my main problems.

4. Basically, step 2 and 3 should be repeated. Thus, the array should filter for every Object with `answered: false`. This array **should update and contain 9 elements** now - However, it doesn't. It still contains 10 elements and I don't know why. I tried to call the filter function again, without success. I tried refactoring some code by moving bits and pieces around, but nothing worked for me. Additionally, when checking for the right answer, it seems like the answer to the question that has been first answered is saved and will be used to for all the other questions.

Please find my code here:

```js
var data = [{
    question: "Cabrio: Check! Glas wird geext / Na klar gibt es Sex, weil ich parshippe jetzt!",
    options: ["Gzuz", "Bonez MC", "RAF Camora", "LX"],
    answer: "Gzuz",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Die Presse will mich mit Monsterbräuten in Bondfahrzeugen knipsen / Es ist wie Naturgewalten, weil Blitze vor dem Don erleuchten (Donner leuchten), Bitches!",
    options: ["Kollegah", "Farid Bang", "Ali As", "Fatoni"],
    answer: "Kollegah",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Frage: Was haben ein Rabbi, ein Priester, ein Koch mit 3 Eiern / ein Flyerverteiler mit einem Paket Flyern / ein Esel, zwei Geier, ich und 300 Freier gemeinsam? / Könnten alle dein Vadder sein!",
    options: ["Snaga", "Pillath", "Torch", "KC Rebel"],
    answer: "Snaga",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Denkt ihr, die Flüchtlinge sind in Partyboote gestiegen / mit dem großen Traum, im Park mit Drogen zu dealen?",
    options: ["Tarek", "Maxim", "Nico", "DJ Craft"],
    answer: "Tarek",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Rapper reden über Muskeln oder Brustumfang / Ich bin so ein Sklave, ich muss Benz fahren aus Gruppenzwang",
    options: ["Shindy", "Bushido", "Fler", "Sido"],
    answer: "Shindy",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Widerlich, Bitch! / Also glaub nicht, dass du Hund hier'n Aufreißer wirst (Hirn auf Reis servierst) wie'n China-Imbiss",
    options: ["Kollegah", "Majo", "Jizi", "Gozpel"],
    answer: "Kollegah",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Ich bin nicht nur der King dieser Mucke – ich bin diese Mucke!",
    options: ["Kool Savas", "Eko Fresh", "Moe Mitchell", "Kaas"],
    answer: "Kool Savas",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Ich brauch' Para, damit F*ckf*tzen blasen, ich muss Fixkosten tragen, die kann Rick Ross nicht zahlen.",
    options: ["SSIO", "Schwester Ewa", "Xatar", "Abdi"],
    answer: "SSIO",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Hater schauen und bauen sich einen Fake-Account, doch wissen, dass mein Album hitlastig ist/Hitlers Dick isst wie Eva Braun.",
    options: ["Ali As", "Kollegah", "Farid Bang", "Majo"],
    answer: "Ali As",
    answered: false
  },
  {
    question: "Dein Rap ist voller Tiefsinnigkeit/ Dass man als Zuhörer denkt, dein Schniedel ist klein",
    options: ["SSIO", "Edgar Wasser", "Juse Ju", "Azad"],
    answer: "SSIO",
    answered: false
  },
];

//Generate a score variable
var score = 0;

//Generate an array, which includes all the unanswered questions
var unansweredArr = data.filter(function(question) {
  return question.answered === false;
});

//Random Number in order to get a random element from the array
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * unansweredArr.length);

//Display random element/question in HTML
$("#question").text(unansweredArr[randomIndex].question);
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $("#Option" + (i + 1)).text(unansweredArr[randomIndex].options[i]);
}

//What happens when the person answers the question
$(".Rapper").on("click", function() {
  unansweredArr[randomIndex].answered = true;
  var selected = $(this).text();
  var trueAnswer = unansweredArr[randomIndex].answer;

  //Check if answered correctly
  if (auswahl === wahreAntwort) {
    //Increase score by 1 and ask next question
    console.log("Correct");
    next();
    return score = score + 1;
  } else {
    console.log("Wrong");
    next();
    return score;
  }
});

function next() {
  var unansweredArr = data.filter(function(question) {
    return question.answered === false;
  });

  //Check if the array of unanswered questions is not empty
  if (unansweredArr.length !== 0) {
    //New random number
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * unansweredArr.length);

    //Display question and options in html
    $("#question").text(unansweredArr[randomIndex].question);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      $("#Option" + (i + 1)).text(unansweredArr[randomIndex].options[i]);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Game Over");
    console.log(score);
  }
}
/* Problems: 
 - unansweredArr does not update after a question has been answered.
 - Answer to the first question will be the answer for the following questions.
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="home.html">Zurück.</a>
<div>
  <!-- Frage Block -->
  <div>
    <p id="question">-- This is, where the punchline will be displayed --</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Antwort Möglichkeiten -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="Rapper" id="Option1">Rapper 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="Rapper" id="Option2">Rapper 2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="Rapper" id="Option3">Rapper 3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="Rapper" id="Option4">Rapper 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that requests for debugging help must include code **in the question itself**. If the code is too long (which it probably is) then you should create a simplified, stripped-down version that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define the same variables `randomIndex` and `unansweredArr` as global variables and as local variables in the function `next`.

When you update their value in the function `next`, the global variables with the same names do not change.

As a consequence you are always marking the *first* random question as answered:

```
unansweredArr[randomIndex].answered = true;
```

These are the global variables, and `randomIndex` does not reflect the most recently generated number.

Solution: remove the word `var` from before these variable names in the function `next`.

I did not check for other errors, but this one explains the behaviour you describe.